# YouTube Data API v3: Modified version of YouTube trending that only includes videos from subscribed to channels

Tags: java, performance, youtube

I have made a program that sort of mimics YouTube trending, but only with videos from channels that I am subscribed to. It looks at each [`Subscription`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/Subscription.html), converts the subscription to a [`Channel`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/Channel.html), gets the channel's uploads [`PlayList`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/Playlist.html), converts each [`PlayListItem`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/PlaylistItem.html) to a [`Video`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/Video.html), and finally filters the videos to only include new uploads and then sorts by views.

It works, I guess, but is so painfully slow that the app is unusable. Manually looping through everything takes too much time. I am subscribed to too many channels, and each channel has too many uploads. I tried to shed time by replacing loops with streams where I could, but it doesn't really help.

The primary class in the program, and the only one I will be posting here, is `APICaller.java`.

```java
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class APICaller {

    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS = "client_secret.json";
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
            Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Better YouTube Trending";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    public static List<Video> generateVideos() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        YouTube youtubeService = getService();
        List<Subscription> subscriptions = getSubscriptions(youtubeService);
        List<String> playLists = getPlayLists(youtubeService, subscriptions);
        List<PlaylistItem> playlistItems = getPlayListItems(youtubeService, playLists);
        List<Video> videos = getVideos(youtubeService, playlistItems);

        videos.sort(APICaller::comparison);

        return videos;
    }

    private static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);
        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    private static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = APICaller.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    private static List<Subscription> getSubscriptions(YouTube youtubeService) throws IOException {
        List<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();
        YouTube.Subscriptions.List request = youtubeService.subscriptions().list("snippet");
        SubscriptionListResponse response;
        String nextPageToken = "";
        for (boolean first = true; nextPageToken != null; first = false) {
            if (first) {
                response = request.setMine(true)
                        .setMaxResults(50L)
                        .execute();
            } else {
                response = request.setMine(true)
                        .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                        .setMaxResults(50L)
                        .execute();
            }
            subscriptions.addAll(response.getItems());
            nextPageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
        }
        return subscriptions;
    }

    private static List<String> getPlayLists(YouTube youtubeService, List<Subscription> subscriptions) throws IOException {
        List<String> playLists = new ArrayList<>();
        YouTube.Channels.List request = youtubeService.channels().list("contentDetails");
        subscriptions.forEach(s -> {
            try {
                String id = s.getSnippet().getResourceId().getChannelId();
                ChannelListResponse response = request.setId(id).execute();
                playLists.add(response.getItems().get(0).getContentDetails().getRelatedPlaylists().getUploads());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return playLists;
    }

    private static List<PlaylistItem> getPlayListItems(YouTube youtubeService, List<String> playLists) throws IOException {
        List<PlaylistItem> videos = new ArrayList<>();
        YouTube.PlaylistItems.List request = youtubeService.playlistItems().list("snippet");
        playLists.forEach(playlist -> {
            try {
                PlaylistItemListResponse response;
                String nextPageToken = "";
                for (boolean first = true; nextPageToken != null; first = false) {
                    if (first) {
                        response = request.setPlaylistId(playlist)
                                .setMaxResults(50L)
                                .execute();
                    } else {
                        response = request.setPlaylistId(playlist)
                                .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                                .setMaxResults(50L)
                                .execute();
                    }
                    videos.addAll(response.getItems());
                    nextPageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return videos;
    }

    private static List<Video> getVideos(YouTube youtubeService, List<PlaylistItem> playlistItems) throws IOException {
        List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<>();
        YouTube.Videos.List request = youtubeService.videos().list("snippet,statistics");
        playlistItems.forEach(playlistItem -> {
            String id = playlistItem.getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId();
            try {
                VideoListResponse response = request.setId(id).execute();
                if (isNewVideo(response.getItems().get(0))) {
                    videos.add(response.getItems().get(0));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return videos;
    }

    private static boolean isNewVideo(Video video) {
        LocalDate publishedAt = LocalDate.parse(video.getSnippet().getPublishedAt().toString().substring(0, 10));
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(publishedAt, LocalDate.now()) < 7;
    }

    private static int comparison(Video video1, Video video2) {
        return (int)(video1.getStatistics().getViewCount().longValue()) - (int)(video2.getStatistics().getViewCount().longValue());
    }
}
```

The program is run by calling the one `public` method in the class: `generateVideos()`. You would need to use your own `client_secret.json` file, which you can download [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). The method returns returns a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of videos, which would then be used elsewhere in the program to populate the GUI. I haven't included all that because it isn't really relevant to my question.

So, how would you improve this code? Are there any glaring inefficiencies, obvious mistakes, extraneous steps, and the like?

Comment: I don't know youtube api, but it seems me you are making distinct requests limited to the first `50` results, so if you have a great number of items to retrieve this could explain why it is so slow.

Comment: If I read this correctly, you page throug *all* the results, never stopping until the very last page. How many results and how many calls for 50 items is this in total? How long does a single `list()` call take?

Comment: @dariosicily The Youtube API only allows a maximum of 50 results with each response. You have to paginate through the whole thing in order to get all the results.

Comment: I see, then if you have a great number of items you are obliged to do several calls of the API.

Comment: @dariosicily I initially set it to return some absurdly large number of results with one call, but it always returned a maximum of 50 anyway. That led me to this on Stack Overflow: [Youtube API V3; Maximum number of videos only 50?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803732/youtube-api-v3-maximum-number-of-videos-only-50)

Comment: Did you tried to move the retrieval of playlists and videos of each subscription in a dedicated thread ? Also, if this will run on a schedule, you could save the last result so that you wont list items older than that one (like a message offset).

Comment: @gervais.b My knowledge of how multithreading works is somewhat limited. Is there a way to run each step in separate threads, when each one requires data from the previous one? Or, more precisely, since the threads can't run simultaneously anyway, would multithreading help in this case?

Comment: Threads can be seen as parts of your code that are executed "in parallel". But you can pass the parameters that you want. Why do you think that they "can't run simultaneously" ?

Comment: @gervais.b Maybe what I’m saying makes no sense, but if each of the method calls in `generateVideos` requires data from the previous one, I can’t run any until the previous one completes. Would putting them into separate threads still allow them to run simultaneously?

Comment: You could generate one video per thread but that may be too much. At the first step you could try to move the creation of one playlist and children (PlaylistItem and Video) in one thread per subscription.

Comment: @gervais.b I know next to nothing about Java multithreading. Any way you can write up a quick summary with some code as an answer? Thanks.